# Python connection with Hive database in HDInsight

Tags: python, python-3.x, hive, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to create connection to Hive hosted in HDInsight cluster through my python script and getting below error-

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ClassLoader.java", line 357, in java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
  File "Launcher.java", line 349, in sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass
  File "ClassLoader.java", line 424, in java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
  File "URLClassLoader.java", line 382, in java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "org.jpype.JPypeContext.java", line 330, in org.jpype.JPypeContext.callMethod
  File "Method.java", line 498, in java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  File "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java", line 43, in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
  File "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", line 62, in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
  File "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", line -2, in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
  File "DriverManager.java", line 247, in java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection
  File "DriverManager.java", line 664, in java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection
  File "HiveDriver.java", line 105, in org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect
Exception: Java Exception
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s.py", line 5, in <module>
    "/root/jdbc/hive-jdbc-1.2.1000.2.6.5.3009-43.jar")
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 412, in connect
    jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 230, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
    return jpype.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, *dargs)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransportException
```

My Script is -

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
       "jdbc:hive2://10.20.30.40:10001/default;transportMode=http;ssl=false;httpPath=/hive2",
       ["username", "password"],
       "/root/jdbc/hive-jdbc-1.2.1000.2.6.5.3009-43.jar")
```

I have exported CLASSPATH wil all jar files.

Comment: can you share your CLASSPATH jars list?

Comment: use the `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/1.2.1/hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar jar` and share the results?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s.py", line 5, in <module>
    "/root/jdbc/hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar")
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 412, in connect
    jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 230, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
    return jpype.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, *dargs)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransportException

Comment: CLASSPATH- 
[root@hostname]# echo $CLASSPATH
/root/jdbc/hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar:/root/jdbc/httpclient-4.4.jar:/root/jdbc/httpcore-4.4.4.jar

Comment: Replace hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar instead of /root/jdbc/hive-jdbc-1.2.1000.2.6.5.3009-43.jar

Comment: same error- Traceback (most recent call last): File "s.py", line 5, in <module> "hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar") File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 412, in connect jconn = jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs) File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init_.py", line 230, in _jdbc_connect_jpype return jpype.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, *dargs) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransportException [root@hosname ]# – aks 16 mins ago   Delete

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

The error is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` which specifies that the execution is not able to find the jar */root/jdbc/hive-jdbc-1.2.1000.2.6.5.3009-43.jar*.I believe it's only placed in a host from where you are executing the code. I would suggest placing the jar file in the same directory structure in all the nodes in the cluster and have a check on permissions so that the user executing the job has access to that path.